# AttributeError with Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm literally starting in Pyglet, and I tried the simplest program with it (A hello world window).

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=640, height=480, caption="Hola Mundo!")
pyglet.app.run()
```

But when I run it, I get an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'module' has no attribute 'window'
```

Comment: You likely have a file called `pyglet.py` in your working directory.

Comment: Rename that file and delete pyglet.pyc

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you have a file in the cwd called `pyglet`. When importing modules, python first looks at the cwd before looking in the global list of installed packages.

Rename that file and delete the corresponding `pyglet.pyc` file.

*Posting the information from bernie in an answer since it is likely correct.  Trying to reduce the unanswered question queue.*